# Trivialization of Pontryagin square on oriented $4$-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, classifying-spaces, fibration

I'm sorry for not clearly stating my question, thanks to Robert Bruner for answering my original question, let me restate it.

Let $\mathcal{P}:H^2(-,\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^4(-,\mathbb{Z}/4)$ be the Pontryagin square.

My question: Can we find a fibration
$f:X\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$ with fiber $K(G,1)\times K(H,2)$ such that $\mathcal{P}(fg)=0$ for any oriented $4$-manifold $M$ and any map $g:M\to X$?
(Here $K(G,n)$ is the Eilenberg-MacLane space, $G$ and $H$ are finite abelian groups.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The original question was whether $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is non-zero when $x$ is. This answers that question, and was aimed at generic $r$, $p$ and $K$.  Special cases may have special answers.

By Brown representability, $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is represented by a map $K \to K(Z/2r,2p)$.  In the fiber of this map, the image of $x$ is still non-zero, but its Pontrjagin square will be zero.

Comment: I edited my question, the fiber of your example is $K(\mathbb{Z}/2r,2p-1)$ and $2p-1\ge3$.

Comment: My example is a space, the fiber of $\mathcal{P}(x)$.    I am not sure what you mean by referring to its fiber.    Are you thinking about the universal case, $F = Fiber(\mathcal{P}(\iota_2) : K(Z/2,2) \to K(Z/4,4))$?   It has two non-zero homotopy groups, $\pi_2 F = Z/2$ and $\pi_3(F) = Z/4)$.

Comment: I mean the fiber of $F\to K$ where $F$ is the fiber of $\mathcal{P}(x)$.